# Update a List<Entity> in EF4

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to update a list of contents with EF4. However I have not found a way how to do it.  My current code is as follows:

```
db.NotifContents.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
List<NotifContent> notifContentList = db.NotifContents
     .Where(u => u.FKID_Contact == contactId && !u.Sent && u.CanSendMail)
     .ToList();

List<NotifContent> newNotifContentList = new List<NotifContent>();

foreach(NotifContent notifContent in notifContentList)
{
    notifContent.NextMailSend = dtNextMailSend;        newNotifContentList.Add(notifContent);
    try
    {
        //db.CreateObjectSet<NotifContent>().Attach(notifContent);
        //db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(notifContent, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

        db.AddToNotifContents(notifContent);
        ObjectStateEntry notifContentsEntry = db.ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntry(notifContent);
        notifContentsEntry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
    }
}
```

However the second update will always fail, and understandably since the Entity is attached to the datacontext.

How can I do a bulk update in EF4?

UPDATE

Change the loop as follows

```
            foreach(NotifContent notifContent in notifContentList)
        {
            notifContent.NextMailSend = dtNextMailSend;
            db.NotifContents.Attach(notifContent);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(notifContent, EntityState.Modified);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
```

and I am getting the following error :-

An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Comment: What does `db.AddToNotifContents` do?

Comment: it adds the entity to the set no?

Comment: Sorry, of course, it is the generated method on the object context.

Comment: I think you need to [detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) your `notifContent` first.

Comment: GertArnold as you can see solved my own problem :)  Very good Extension to EF!

Comment: Way to go Johann! Don't forget to accept your own answer in due time.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the EntityFramework.Extended Library, and there is a method called .Update to do bulk updates

So I resoved as follows :-

```
            var notifContents =
            db.NotifContents.Where(u => u.FKID_Contact == contactId && u.Sent == false && u.CanSendMail);
        db.NotifContents.Update(notifContents, u => new NotifContent{NextMailSend = dtNextMailSend});
```